# Format function returning minutes instead of months?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While exploring the new function `FORMAT` I have come across the following issue, would like to know if any one else has faced a similar problem and found the fix for this, or if it is a bug?

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'mm/dd/yyyy','en-US');
SELECT GETDATE();
```

Output:

1. 02/02/2013
2. 2013-06-02 12:02:54.067

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function argument is a .net format string, where `mm` is minutes and `MM` is months. You specified minutes, so minutes is what you got.

There are example format strings at [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az4se3k1.aspx). As an alternative to `MM/dd/yyyy` you can also use just `d` which is the Short Date Format specifier (detailed on the linked page).

Comment: +1 but note that if you use `d` you lose leading zeros.

Answer (score 4):

The `FORMAT` function is case sensitive
As such, "mm" stands for minutes and "MM" stands for month.

You can see a complete table of combinations and letter meanings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). This is the `.NET` article for date and time formatting, which SQL Server's `FORMAT` is using.